# Tokenize API not integrating

Tags: curl, payment-gateway

I am working with YouCanPay Tokenize API [https://youcanpay.com/api/tokenize]. I am using the Sandbox private key for testing and using all parameters mentioned in the [documentation](https://youcanpay.com/docs/api#tokenize_payment). I have also enabled Sandbox mode in my YouCanPay account. The error I am getting after hitting this API is this:

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Sandbox key used on live mode"
}
```

I am expecting to get this response as it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://youcanpay.com/docs/api#tokenize_payment):

```json
{
    "transaction_id": "840f1c8a-6554-45d5-a1ad-f8a48f928dcf",
    "token": "cp500014337"
}
```

Comment: It's said to use Merchant account's private key. Not sandbox private key. It's up to the sandbox key

Comment: I am actually using the Sandbox private key for testing. I have enabled Sandbox mode in my account also.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the API I was using is used for live transactions, not for the Sandbox. For Sandbox testing, the API is [https://youcanpay.com/sandbox/api/tokenize]. It was not mentioned in the documentation, I just installed their SDK and after reading the code, I got it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).